# How to change webbrowser's display screen on WindowsPhone 7 apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm making an app about displaying lastest goals. in that app i'm using webbrowser-control. And i want to show my url links specifically. For example i want to show the page's 100 px height and 100 px width. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your page, invoke the webbrowser control with the following properties

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Height="100" Width="100"/>
```